# How to show response json

Tags: php, json, react-native

I need to show response. For example title

```
stdClass Object
(
[product] => stdClass Object
    (
        [title] => shoes
        [id] => 44
        [created_at] => 2018-11-08T10:58:58Z
        [updated_at] => 2018-11-08T10:59:01Z
        [type] => variable
        [status] => publish
        [downloadable] => 
        [virtual] => 
        [permalink] => http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/
        [sku] => 
        [price] => 7000
        [regular_price] => 0
        [sale_price] => 
        [price_html] =>
```

This is my code in react native to show response:

```
handlePress =()=> {
  fetch('http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx.php',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "type": "select",
      "args": {
          "table": "product",
          "columns": [
              "title"
          ],
          "limit": "1"
      }
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    Alert.alert("Product Name  " + responseJson[0].name);
  }).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
}
```

**Error:** Json parse error: Unsuspected identifier "stdClass"

I think columns or table select have problem but in console error is about stdClass.

Comment: What you're sending **isn't JSON**, see https://json.org/.

Comment: Side note (it's not the problem, the problem is as stated above: you're not sending JSON): You're missing the check of `ok` on the `response` before calling `response.json()`. It's not just you, most people seem to miss this out, so many that I [wrote it up on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdClass is part of PHP. It seems you do something like returning this stdClass-Object (like vardump($yourObject);).

You need to send an fully valid json. In PHP you can do it with `echo json_encode($yourObj);`

Comment: Thank You! Now response is undefined. {"product":{"title":"\u06a9\u062a \u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f","id":44,"

Comment: How can I select product and title?

Answer (score 0):

To use json (e.g in JS), you need to decode/parse Json. After this, you can access it like an general JS-Object.

```
var json = '{"name":'BimBom', "age":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.name);  // result in BimBom
console.log(obj.age);  // result in 42
```

Comment: @Alireza did this helped you out?